# How do I make my repository remove child entities and not just navigation properties from my aggregate root

Tags: entity-framework, domain-driven-design, repository, entity-framework-4.1

I'm trying to build a functioning repository using Entity Framework. I feel like I'm missing something really obvious somewhere. Lets say I have `IRepository<Person>` which has many `Address` in an `ICollection<Address> Addresses`.

When I call `Person.Addressess.Remove(sameAddress)` I understand this will only remove the navigation (in this case will try to set the `PersonID` column to null in the database).

The issue is I want to delete it somehow from the aggregate root, so I can just send the `Person` object to my repository like so `personRepository.Update(person)` and not have to manually delete the address or create a address repository.

Perhaps I'm searching for the wrong thing but I would have thought this was a common issue, yet I can't seem to find anything on line.

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a future EF release might allow what you're asking for:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsimmons/archive/2010/01/31/deleting-foreign-key-relationships-in-ef4.aspx

Comment: What is the recommendation in 2021 and EF Core 5?